# jQuery object as jQuery's .on() methods selector parameter

Tags: jquery

Is there any way of using previously registered jQuery object as jQuery's `.on()` methods selector?

I mean:

```
//The code below doesn't work as expected.
$containerElement= $('#containerElement');
$myButton = $('#mybutton')

$containerElement.on('click', $myButton , function(){ //<-- how can I use my previously registered $myButton element here?
    alert('yeyy!');
})
```

Comment: Did you mean `$(this)` ?

Comment: Why cant you use $("#mybutton").on('click', function(){});

Comment: Because of some reason I had to collect all events on #myContainerElement

Comment: The answer is no, but you already know what the selector should be (`'#mybutton'`) so just use that instead.

Comment: No there is not, the second selector is more like a filter, and in theory only accepts strings, but if I remember correctly you can use a single native DOM node, so doing `$myButton.get(0)` should work.

Comment: @adeneo no, only string selector. But for sure, should be tested

Comment: As a sidenote, works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/6/

Comment: @adeneo thank you but I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @adeneo no, selector for target is ignored: http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/7/

Comment: @A.Wolff - Ah, yes it is? But another question, why delegate the event when you already have the button, why not attach it directly?

Comment: @A.Wolff - using jQuery `.selector` works -> http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/9/, but it's undocumented

Comment: @adeneo good point but, this won't use delegation because object targeted still need to be already in the DOM and anyway `selector` property is deprecated. I'm agree with your previous comment, asking why OP would need that

Comment: @A.Wolff - Exactly, if the element truly is dynamic and a delegated event handler really is needed, `$myButton` would be empty at that point, so this makes no sense at all really ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$containerElement.on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is($myButton)) alert('yeyy!');
})
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/8/) (from adeneo's one)

More relevant [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kaC/11/)

Comment: Thank you @A. Wolff. I need that beacuse I was trying to keep something simple. But now I see clearly that It became more complex than I think.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, using `event.data` (https://api.jquery.com/event.data/):

```
$containerElement.on('click', { button : $myButton }, function(event) {
    event.data.button.css({ color : "#FFFFFF"} );
}
```

The 2nd parameter object's key => value pairs are added to the event object and are accessible via the `event.data` object. Makes passing things into event handlers for use very easy, so you don't have to find it later.

Comment: Really? How does that bind the event to the button, it just passes the button as data?

Comment: "Description: An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound. "

Comment: But the button variable is defined in a higher scope, so it's already available, you don't have to pass it at all. The point wasn't really to access the button inside the event handler, but to filter the event handler so it only fires when clicking the button.

Comment: True, but his example may have been a slimmed down version of what his final code will look like. His function may not have had the `$myButton` variable available in that scope; it could have been part of a higher level object, etc. I try not to assume.

Comment: If it's not part of that scope, you can't pass it to the event handler either, so no cigar.

Comment: it all depends on his JS structure. his event handler function could be defined in one place and only have to worry about `event.data.button`; the binding code could be defined in another place and have access (through one mechanism or another) to $myButton. Basic stuff here.